# swinject - IOS - Swit - present a viewcontroller located in a xib file = crash

Tags: ios, swift, swinject

I use swinject with swift 3.
I try to present on my current view controller, another view controller, located in a .xib file.

if I do it in a project without swinject, it works.
in my project, using swinject it crashes : 
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

here is the code I use to define the view controller :

```
let container = Container() { c in
    c.register(testViewController.self) { r in
        let myVC = testViewController(nibName: "testView", bundle: nil)
        return myVC
    }
}
```

here is how I try to present the testViewController on my current viewController (on a button click IBAction for example):

```
self.present(container.resolve(testViewController.self)!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I Tried different solution without success.
I cannot remove swinject ( this choice is not mine ), and I believe that it is a good idea, even if I am not easy with it.
I need to use .xib file because I have a lot of viewcontroller, to present, at different steps.

thanks for any help.
Olivier

Comment: What is the error message output to your Xcode console?

Comment: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: @olivierrobin `NSException` crash usually displays more information about the issue, namely the reason of the crash. Could you add the entire crash description?

Comment: Hi,no, unfortunatly, it is too late, I removed swinject since I could not find what was wrong.